# Sliding up panel set panelHeight as Textview Child height

Tags: java

I am using umano sliding up panel library. I need to set panel's height to be same as a second Textview height. Example a textview.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/testtest"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="65dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="main"/>
     <TextView

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"/>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Is there any method which it can take textview height and send it in umano panel's heigt>?
Or if i can calculate textview text size to height in dp